# How to fill StripeCheckout's shippingAddress && billingAddress from code [REACT ,STRIPE ]

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

so I want to load the stripe Checkout's modal with billing and shipping address filled using data stored in cookies , as  want logged users who have set a default shipping and billing address to not bother filling the fields every time they make a purchase  .

here is my stripe checkout code in react :

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useContext} from 'react'
import {FlexRow,LightParagraph,Border ,RawLink,Card} from '../../../Style/global'
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/core'
import {CartContext} from '../../../Context/CartProvider'
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout'
import axios from 'axios'

const CheckoutPayment=(props)=> {
    const {method}=props
    const [productsToProcces, setproductsToProcces] = useState([])
    const {cart} = useContext(CartContext)


    useEffect(() => {
         setproductsToProcces(cart.map(item=>({ title:item.itemName, price:item.itemPrice, quantity:item.quantity, images:item.images})))
    }, [])


    const handelToken=async(token)=>{
        try {
            const stripeResponse =await  axios.post('http://localhost:4000/stripe/checkout',{
                token,
                product:{
                  products:products.map(p=>p.title),
                  amount:products.map(item=>item.price * item.quantity).reduce((a, b)=> a + b , 0)*100
                }
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
       
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Card >
               <FlexRow no100={true} justify="space-between" css={css`padding:1rem;`}  >
                  <LightParagraph size={.8} mgb={0} css={css`width:100px;`}>Contact</LightParagraph>
                  <LightParagraph size={.8} mgb={0}>sad_fatah@outlook.com</LightParagraph>
                  <RawLink to="checkout/information" >Change</RawLink>
               </FlexRow>

               <Border css={css`margin-bottom:0;`} />
               <FlexRow no100={true} justify="space-between" css={css`padding:1rem;`}  >
                    <LightParagraph size={.8} mgb={0} css={css`width:100px;`}>Contact</LightParagraph>
                    <LightParagraph size={.8} mgb={0}>ASKJALKSLASA, ASASA, 4500 OUARZAZATE , Morocco</LightParagraph>
                    <RawLink to="checkout/information" >Change</RawLink>
               </FlexRow>

               <Border css={css`margin-bottom:0;`} />
               <FlexRow no100={true} justify="space-between"  css={css`padding:1rem;`} >
                    <LightParagraph size={.8} mgb={0} css={css`width:100px;`} >Method</LightParagraph>
                    <LightParagraph size={.8} mgb={0} >
                         {method || 'DHL Express '} 
                         <span   css={css`${styles.bill__total};${styles.smallMoney}`}>$100.37</span>
                    </LightParagraph>
                    <RawLink to="checkout/information" >Change</RawLink>
               </FlexRow>
            </Card>

            <FlexRow >
               <RawLink to="/checkout/information" size={1}><i className="fas fa-angle-left iconeB"></i> Return to shipping</RawLink>
               <StripeCheckout 
                 stripeKey='pk_test_51HCsVhLkAIHmcekiVfb5aSOF75eJPLKwn7MhbxmQKMVtJrworoCsyNL8Otxs0cdcFYjKMpjejHzChey00DlIkW8b007nxn9KYC'
                 token={handelToken}
                 billingAddress
                 shippingAddress
                 amount={productsToProcces.map(item=>item.price * item.quantity).reduce((a, b)=> a + b , 0)*100}
               />   
           </FlexRow>
        </div>
    )
}

const styles ={
    smallMoney :css` 
    font-size: .9rem;
    color: var(--colorGreyDark);
    `,
    bill__total :css` 
    font-weight: 600;
    `,
}

export default CheckoutPayment
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to pre-fill the billing or shipping address in Stripe's legacy Checkout. As you can see the library you're using only accepts booleans for the `billingAddress` and `shippingAddress` props respectively:

https://github.com/azmenak/react-stripe-checkout/blob/master/StripeCheckout.js#L153-L159

I would consider using Stripe's newer Checkout product which will automatically show/hide the billing address field for you:

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration
- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/customization#billing-address-collection